# Is it possible to automatically wake from suspend?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, power-management, suspend

### Here's my problem:

I have a laptop running Arch that I just keep on at home. It's got a good 4 hour battery life, but sometimes my daughter is playing near where it's kept and ends out pulling the plug. Well, when I get home 5 hours later, my laptop had a hard shutdown.

Additionally, sometimes I'll leave it suspended and forget about it for a day or so - same problem.

### Here's my proposition:

So my thought was that I could make a cron job that runs every 15 or 30 minutes or something, checking the battery life. If the battery life is < N minutes left, I could just hibernate the laptop. This would work fine if my laptop is in normal 'on'. But if I'm suspended, not so much. So my question is two fold - is there a better way to do this, and if not, is it possible to do some sort of monitoring in suspend mode - basically just run that cron job?

### Here's what worked:

Following the [uswsusp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uswsusp) instructions on the Arch wiki, I installed uswsusp from the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=44473). Using the following command:

```
wayne@jughead:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda2                               partition   530140  56744   -1
```

I discovered `/dev/sda2` was the name of my swap partition. So I set this in my `/etc/suspend.conf`

```
snapshot device = /dev/snapshot
resume device = /dev/sda2
```

I added uresume in my mkinitcpio.conf here:

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect pata scsi sata resume uresume filesystems usbinput fsck"
```

I created `/etc/pm/config.d/module` and put

```
SLEEP_MODULE=uswsusp
```

in it.

Since my laptop was not recognized (`# s2ram --test` displayed `Machine unknown`) I had to use the `--force` option.

In `/usr/lib/pm-utils/module.d/uswsusp` I also changed all of the `s2ram` options to `s2both`.

Comment: You know `rtcwake`? [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/61717) could be inspirational.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/12383/how-to-go-automatically-from-suspend-into-hibernate

Comment: Excellent solutions, if s2both doesn't work out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want [suspend-to-both/hybrid suspend](http://www.pkill.info/linux/man/8-pm-suspend-hybrid/) which should do all the steps of hibernating, including writing RAM to disk, but not actually turn the machine off; instead, it'll go into S3 (standby). If you wake the machine up before the battery dies, it'll be fairly quick; if the battery dies, it'll be just as if you'd hibernated it.

Comment: That looks highly promising - I'll be checking that out this evening!

Comment: Works perfectly! I set it up and yanked the battery and my session came back online.